# What is written in this Chinese painting? (Characters identified: 寧靜致遠)

Tags: meaning, character-identification

Can somebody tell me what is written in this painting?

[image]

http://sino.ro/5976-thickbox_default/pictura-chinezeasca-simbolul-liniste-cod-b68-6.jpg

The Chinese people selling this painting told me it's related to inner peace, tranquility, being a kind o "mantra" they couldn't translate.

Comment: The characters are: 宁静致远 / 寧靜致遠

Comment: anyone could recognize the signature?

Answer (score 3):

The calligraphy writing 寧靜致遠 is a quote origin from an ancient scroll call 淮南子, under the page 主术训.

Here is the whole phrase : 
是故非澹漠无以明志，非宁静无以致远。

The whole phrase is a philosophy, which will take pages to explain. I will try to summarize them.

- 是故非澹漠无以明志 one must be put aside your own crave and obsession to know your goals clearly.
- 非宁静无以致远 :  Without calmness,  one cannot achieve their long term goals

Answer (score 0):

Approximately, if you are calm and rational you'll get farther, or if you don't act rashly and blindly you'll be successful.